# Php PDO mysql give different result than mysql workbentch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i switched from mysql to pdo. i have the following code:

```
$stmt_serverl = $db->prepare("SELECT ID, Name, IP, IP2 FROM serverl WHERE LOWER(Name) LIKE '%:name%'");

if ($row['divs'] == 1) {
    $date_compare = new DateTime('2014-10-15 11:11:10');
    if ($dt > $date_compare) {
        $name = explode('@',strtolower($row['name']));
        print_r($name);
        $full_name = $name[0]."-".$name[1].$name[2];
        $stmt_serverl->bindValue(':name', $name[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    else {
        $name = explode('@',strtolower($row['name']));
        print_r($name);
        $full_name = $name[0]."-".$name[1]."-".$name[2];
        $stmt_serverl->bindValue(':name', $name[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }
elseif ($row['divs'] == 2) {
    $name = explode('@',strtolower($row['name']));
    print_r($name);
    $full_name = $name[0].$name[1]."-".$name[2];
    $stmt_serverl->bindValue(':name', $name[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
$dt = null;

$stmt_serverl->execute();
$result = null;
$result = $stmt_serverl->fetchAll();

// println($query_serverl, $debug, $logfile);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

i get all params ($row['divs'] and $row['name']) from another result set which works just fine.
when i run the query with the $name var i get strange result:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [ID] => 3237
>               [Name] => :Name
>               [IP] => :IP
>               [IP2] => :IP2
>           )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 3236
        [Name] => :Name
        [IP] => :IP
        [IP2] => :IP2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 3235
        [Name] => :Name
        [IP] => :IP
        [IP2] => :IP2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 3234
        [Name] => :Name
        [IP] => :IP
        [IP2] => :IP2
    )
```

)
while running the same query in workbench return 0 results (no match at all)
i can't figure what can be the problem.
thanks
mor

Comment: Your if/else/elseif do nothing.

Comment: ok, i think you are right, but i can't understand how i got the output from the print_4($name) from within the elseif...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quote the placeholder, the database will receive `%:name%` as the value.

Change your SQL to this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, IP, IP2 FROM serverl WHERE LOWER(Name) LIKE :name
```

Than adjust the Binding:

```
$stmt_serverl->bindValue(':name', '%'.$name[1].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Or You can do the concactenation in the SQL itself:

```
SELECT ID, Name, IP, IP2 FROM serverl WHERE LOWER(Name) LIKE CONCAT ('%', :name , '%')
```

Then you bind the same way you are currently binding:

```
$stmt_serverl->bindValue(':name', $name[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thanks both, it's working now. i changed the if to `$row['divs'] == "2"` and fixed the SQL query as mentioned.